# How do I work with a Ruby on Rails polymorphic association within a nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Edited to more clearly ask my question correctly.
I have tried several patterns for implementing polymorphic associations, and I've settled on one that I picked from Chris at GoRails a few years.  It's solid and works with just about any top-level resource that implements a polymorphic association.  A simple example is a Tasks model that exposes Taskable as a polymorphic association.  I can easily set up an association with a single, top-level object like a Project.
Example (all code limited to the question at hand):

app/models/task.rb

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :taskable, polymorphic: true
end
```

app/models/project.rb

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :phases
  has_many :tasks, as: :taskable
end
```

app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  def new 
    @task = @taskable.tasks.new
  end
  # lots of other methods...
end
```

app/controllers/projects/tasks_controller.rb

```
class Projects::TasksController < TasksController 
  before_action :set_taskable

  private 
    def set_taskable
      @taskable = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    end
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do  
  resources :projects do
    resources :phases
    resources :tasks, module: :projects
  end
end
```

So, in any view, I can add links like this:
app/views/tasks/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Edit task', edit_polymorphic_path([@taskable, @task]) %>
```

I can wire up any object to Tasks easily and with minimal code duplication (and not using concerns!) via this pattern.

The issue arises when I need to wire up a nested object.  Note in the routes file that Projects have a one-to-many association with Phases.  Now, if I need to wire up Phases to some Polymorphic association (I'll use Tasks here as an example), I need to create the polymorphic path or url in 3 part notation: <%= link_to 'Edit task', edit_polymorphic_path([@project, @taskable, @task]) %>
I have been scratching my head and searching all over but I have found nothing and I can't even think of a place to start.

I initially set up my routes like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do  
  resources :projects do
    resources :phases do
      resources :tasks, module: :phases
    end
    resources :tasks, module: :projects
  end
end
```

The routes are output correctly, but now I need to pass 3 params to the path call:
<%= link_to 'Edit task', edit_polymorphic_path([@project, @taskable, @task]) %>
However, this breaks my polymorphic view because the argument list is different.  So, I am looking for a way to keep the view polymorphic, regardless of the routing level of the polymorphic association.

I also tried to make this work:
config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do  
  resources :projects do
    resources :phases
    resources :tasks, module: :projects
  end
  resources :phases do
    resources :tasks, module: :phases
  end
end
```

Rails does not like that, of course, because both associations are not represented in the second block, so a full route can't be created.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I maybe missing what your issue is here, but you can just keep nesting your routes:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do  
  resources :projects do
    resources :phases do
      resources :tasks, module: :phases
    end
    resources :tasks, module: :projects
  end
end
```

```rb
#                Prefix Verb URI Pattern                                                     Controller#Action
edit_project_phase_task GET  /projects/:project_id/phases/:phase_id/tasks/:id/edit(.:format) phases/tasks#edit
```

---

**Update**

So you have two routes and you want to use it from a single template for your tasks:

```rb
edit_polymorphic_path([@taskable, @task])           # @taskable is Project
edit_polymorphic_path([@project, @taskable, @task]) # @taskable is Phase
```

You could always use double nested route for everything:

```rb
# this will work with @project or without
edit_polymorphic_path([@project, @taskable, @task])
```

For example:

```rb
<%= edit_polymorphic_path([Project.first, Phase.first, Task.first]) %>
#=> /projects/1/phases/1/tasks/1/edit

<%= edit_polymorphic_path([nil, Project.first, Task.first]) %>
#=> /projects/1/tasks/1/edit
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.  Looking at my question again, I can see I did not ask correctly.  I used the double-nested routes first, and they correctly output the right paths.  However, my deeper question is about the polymorphic view.  I haven't had any success in invoking a three part (double nested route) path when needed instead of the 2 part path (single nested route).  I am going to see if I can update my question to say that more accurately.  I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: That did it!  Nice and simple.